# Problem with 3rd order ODE solution from DSolve

Tags: differential-equations, equation-solving, simplifying-expressions, symbolic, nonlinear

I Dsolved the following 3rd order ODE:

```
x'[t]==(3x''[t]^2-Sqrt[9x''[t]^4+4x'''[t]^2])/(2x'''[t])
```

Mathematica (version 8) gave me three solutions including the following two:

```
x[t] == +/-(Sqrt[-1+t^2 C[1]^2 + 2t C[1]^2 C[2] + C[1]^2 C[2]^2)/C[1] + C[3]
```

The problem is that these do not appear to be solutions to the above equation. When I take the derivative of x and plug them back in the equation, the result is not a truth. It is 'close' to a truth: plugging in numbers yields two sides of the equation that are clearly systematically related. But they are not identical. Can anyone tell me whether other versions of Mathematica give the same answers and if so what is going on?

Comment: Can you include the code you used to generate the solutions? When I try to `DSolve` that equation in v10.0, it returns unevaluated/

Comment: Here is the code:  DSolve[Derivative[1][x][t] == (
  3 (x^\[Prime]\[Prime])[t]^2 - Sqrt[9 (x^\[Prime]\[Prime])[t]^4 + 4 
\!\(\*SuperscriptBox[\(x\), \*
TagBox[
RowBox[{"(", "3", ")"}],
Derivative],
MultilineFunction->None]\)[t]^2])/(2 
\!\(\*SuperscriptBox[\(x\), \*
TagBox[
RowBox[{"(", "3", ")"}],
Derivative],
MultilineFunction->None]\)[t]), x, t]

Comment: Sorry. I didn't include a set of parentheses in the original equation. It should be: x'[t]==(3x''[t]^2-Sqrt[9x''[t]^4+4x'''[t]^2])/(2x'''[t]).  In other words, 2x'''[t] is all in the denominator.

Comment: Can you please add that post, properly formatted? It will make it more likely that you will get help.

Comment: I see similar behavior with version 10.4.  Probably, it has to do with branch cuts.

Comment: Does that mean that there is a bug in DSolve? I think I am having a crisis of faith, so to speak. How would I go about getting solutions to the equation? Should I try MatLab?

Comment: The problem is with `Solve`, which is called by `DSolve`.  Probably, the solutions are valid for some values of the constants but not by others.  I am working on a solution.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I don't know whether the following bit of information may be useful, but it seems to me it might be relevant. The differential equation requires the velocity, x'[t], to be between -1 and 1. So I wondered whether the associated constant of integration, which I assumed would be C[1] must also be between -1 and 1. However, when I tried to limit the solutions to such a condition, the problem did not go away. But perhaps there are other restrictions that would work.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, the two `DSolve` solutions are correct, but `Simplify` seems unable to show this.  With

```
eq = D[x[t], t] - (3 D[x[t], t, t]^2 - Sqrt[9 D[x[t], t, t]^4 + 4 D[x[t], t, t, t]^2])
    /(2 D[x[t], t, t, t]);
s = DSolve[eq == 0, x[t], t] // Flatten
(* {x[t] -> t C[1] + 1/2 t^2 C[2] + C[3], 
    x[t] -> -(Sqrt[-1 + t^2 C[1]^2 + 2 t C[1]^2 C[2] + C[1]^2 C[2]^2]/C[1]) + C[3], 
    x[t] -> Sqrt[-1 + t^2 C[1]^2 + 2 t C[1]^2 C[2] + C[1]^2 C[2]^2]/C[1] + C[3]} *)
```

we find, for instance,

```
Simplify[(Unevaluated[D[x[t], t] - (3 D[x[t], t, t]^2 - 
    Sqrt[9 D[x[t], t, t]^4 + 4 D[x[t], t, t, t]^2])/(2 D[x[t], t, t, t])] /. s[[2]])]
```

gives a lengthy expression that is not explicitly `0`.  So, let us solve the ODE by a slightly different approach.  First, `Solve` for `D[x[t], t, t, t]`.

```
eq1 = Solve[eq == 0, D[x[t], t, t, t]][[1, 1]] /. Rule -> Subtract
```

yielding a expression equivalent to

```
eq1 = D[x[t], t, t, t] - (3 D[x[t], t] D[x[t], t, t]^2)/(-1 + D[x[t], t]^2)
```

which `DSolve` can more easily handle.

```
s1 = DSolve[eq1 == 0, x[t], t] // Flatten
(* {x[t] -> -(Sqrt[-1 + t^2 C[1]^2 + 2 t C[1]^2 C[2] + C[1]^2 C[2]^2]/C[1]) + C[3], 
    x[t] -> Sqrt[-1 + t^2 C[1]^2 + 2 t C[1]^2 C[2] + C[1]^2 C[2]^2]/C[1] + C[3]} *)
```

`s1` is, however, missing one obvious solution, `x[t] -> C[3]`.  The other two solutions are equal to the second and third solutions in `s`.  Substituting either into `eq1` yields

```
Simplify[Unevaluated[D[x[t], t, t, t] - 
    (3 D[x[t], t] D[x[t], t, t]^2)/(-1 + D[x[t], t]^2)] /. s1[[1]]]
(* 0 *)
```

as desired.

So, why the difference?  `eq` contains a `Sqrt`, and `Simplify` does not know what sign the argument of `Sqrt` has.  Without that information, it cannot simplify the expression.  `Solve` does not worry about such issues when called by `DSolve`, and neither did I in obtaining `eq1`, which contains no `Sqrt`.  Consequently, `Simplify` is able to show that the solutions identically satisfy the transformed ODE.  If the sign of the argument of `Sqrt` in the original equation is of issue, then more care must be taken, probably in the form of placing limits on the values of `C[1]` and `C[2]` in the solutions.  Usually, this can be accomplished automatically by using `Reduce` instead of `Solve`.  Surprizingly, I encountered difficulties, as described in my question [111196](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/111196/1063), when attempting to do so.

Comment: Thank you! This is hugely helpful!! @bbgodfrey

Comment: @pstudtmann  I'm glad the answer was useful.  I hope you will become a regular contributor.  To get started,  1) take the introductory [tour] now, 2) when you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge, 3) remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t), and 4) give help too, by answering questions in your areas of expertise.