# Unusual error message from Solve when called by DSolve

Tags: differential-equations, equation-solving, warning-messages, nonlinear

Question [111150](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/111150/1063) presents an equation nonlinear in its leading derivative

```
eq = D[x[t], t] - (3 D[x[t], t, t]^2 - 
    Sqrt[9 D[x[t], t, t]^4 + 4 D[x[t], t, t, t]^2])/(2 D[x[t], t, t, t]);
```

for which

```
DSolve[eq == 0, x[t], t]
```

returns answers that may not satisfy the `eq == 0`.  Because `DSolve` uses `Solve` internally, a typical course of action in such cases is to set

```
SetOptions[Solve, Method -> Reduce];
```

before calling `DSolve`.  In this case, however, subsequently calling `DSolve` yields several error messages, the first of which is,

> Solve::useq: The answer found by Solve contains equational condition(s)
>   {0 == -3 (-Reduce`ReduceVar[2]^2 + Sqrt[Reduce`ReduceVar[2]^4]), ...}. A
>   likely reason for this is that the solution set depends on branch cuts 
>   of Wolfram Language functions. >>

before returning unevaluated.  I have not encountered this error message below.  Moreover, the point of using `Method -> Reduce` is to correctly handle conditional solutions, which often arise in the presence of branch cuts.  I would appreciate advice on how to avoid or work around this issue.  Thanks.

**Addendum**

```
Reduce[eq == 0, D[x[t], t, t, t]]
```

produces a similar error

> Reduce::useq: The answer found by Reduce contains unsolved equation(s) {0 == -2*(-Derivative[3][x][t] + Sqrt[Derivative[3][x][t]^2]), ...}.  A likely reason for this is that the solution set depends on branch cuts of Wolfram Language functions. >>

along with the "answer",

```
(* (0 == -2*(-Derivative[3][x][t] + Sqrt[Derivative[3][x][t]^2]) && 
   Derivative[3][x][t] != 0 && Derivative[2][x][t] == 0 && 
   Derivative[1][x][t] == -1) || (0 == -2*(Derivative[3][x][t] + 
   Sqrt[Derivative[3][x][t]^2]) && Derivative[3][x][t] != 0 && 
   Derivative[2][x][t] == 0 && Derivative[1][x][t] == 1) || (-1 + 
   Derivative[1][x][t]^2 != 0 && 0 == (-3*(Derivative[2][x][t]^2 + 
   Derivative[1][x][t]^2*Derivative[2][x][t]^2 - 
   Sqrt[((1 + Derivative[1][x][t]^2)^2*Derivative[2][x][t]^4)/(-1 + 
   Derivative[1][x][t]^2)^2] + Derivative[1][x][t]^2*
   Sqrt[((1 + Derivative[1][x][t]^2)^2*Derivative[2][x][t]^4)/(-1 + 
   Derivative[1][x][t]^2)^2]))/(-1 + Derivative[1][x][t]^2) && 
   Derivative[1][x][t]*Derivative[2][x][t] != 0 && 
   Derivative[3][x][t] == (3*Derivative[1][x][t]*Derivative[2][x][t]^2)/
   (-1 + Derivative[1][x][t]^2)) *)
```